# How do I create a C++ console/terminal project in XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am using MacBook Pro Mac OS 10.5 with related version of XCode. I am new to this development environment. I want to develop C++ code for a console/terminal-based application using XCode on Mac OS 10.5, but I did not figure out how to create such type of project using XCode. Could anyone briefly describe the steps or refer me to some related tutorials?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

File->New project

Then from the list on the left "Command line utility", and on the right "C++ tool".